# selecting max value excel using Cells(x,y) as input

Tags: excel, max, vba

How do you call the Max function in VBA using a range of Cells (x,y) as input?

E.g., I have two variables, m & n, where n > m

I try to find the Max value within a range of cells using the following code:

```
Cells(Count, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(m, 1): Cells(n, 1))
```

Using that code I keep getting an error "Expected: list separator or )"

Edit, here is the entire code

```
Sub convertFNIRStoCandlesticks()

'Variable declarations
Dim rowCount As Integer             'The total number of rows in use
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Period As Integer
Dim totalPeriods As Integer
Dim PeriodStart As Integer
Dim PeriodEnd As Integer

rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
totalPeriods = rowCount / 6
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For Count = 1 To totalPeriods
    Period = Count - 1
    PeriodStart = (Period * 6) + 1
    m = (Period * 6) + 1
    PeriodEnd = (Period * 6) + 6
    n = PeriodEnd
    Cells(Count, 2) = Cells(PeriodStart, 1)
    Cells(Count, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(PeriodStart, 1), Cells(PeriodEnd, 1)))
    Cells(Count, 5) = Cells(PeriodEnd, 1)
Next Count


End Sub
```

Comment: do it this way: `Cells(Count, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(m, 1), Cells(n, 1)))`

Comment: I keep getting wrong number of arguments or invalid argument assignment. Any ideas?

Comment: did you copy-paste it? not such error using my function. However, what are: `m`, `n` and `count`?

Comment: yes to the C&P. m is the row number for the beginning of the time window, n is the row number for the end of the time window, count is the row number for where I put the returned value.

Comment: code is correct- I see the same in the answer below therefore I'm sure. What are current values of all three variables? are you sure that your error is exactly on the line in question? could you provide more of your macro for analysis?

Comment: Sure, the entire code is in the initial post now

Comment: not such an error which you have... possibly your data in excel result with the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Max` on `Application.WorksheetFunction` where you use a `Range` from `Cells(m, 1)` to `Cells(n, 1)`:

```
Cells(Count, 4)=Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(m, 1),Cells(n, 1)))
```

This will return max into `Cells(Count, 4)`